# Flask - getlist

Tags: python, flask

Why do I not get a response for getlist function for an ImmutableMultiDict when using a number enclosed in single tick as a string, but I get the response for literally typing the same things?

Here are 2 things I tried:

```
key="'"+str(j)+"'"
print(key)
data = request.form.getlist(key)
print(data)
data = request.form.getlist('1')
print(data)
```

Here is the result I got:

```
'1'
[]
['Can't show answer (secret)']
```